# No puedo filtrar una lista en base a un intervalo de otro archivo

Tags: r, bucle-for, bucles, filtro

Soy nuevo en R y me ha costado mucho lograr este pequeño programa. Necesito filtrar una tabla usando distintos intervalos de valores, pero no he logrado conseguirlo.

Apliqué el siguiente for loop, el proceso nunca termina, y al darle stop arroja el warning y bdnf con 0 observaciones, y el nombre de las columnas crom, cromi, cromf y meth. Intento ir acumulando los valores filtrados en la variable bdnf.

```
for (j in 1:chromStart)
+   {
+   for (k in 1:chromEnd)
+     {bdnf <- filter(X, cromf >= j & cromf <= k)}}

Warning messages:
1: In 1:chromStart :
  numerical expression has 4 elements: only the first used
2: In 1:chromEnd :
  numerical expression has 4 elements: only the first used
```

Esta es la tabla a filtrar (X), en base a la columna cromf

```
# A tibble: 71 x 4
   Crom      cromi     cromf   meth
   <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 chr2  109674711 109674712 0     
 2 chr2  109674743 109674744 0     
 3 chr2  109674752 109674753 0.1   
 4 chr2  109674770 109674771 0     
 5 chr2  109674789 109674790 0     
 6 chr2  109674810 109674811 0     
 7 chr2  109674863 109674864 0     
 8 chr2  109674866 109674867 0     
 9 chr2  109674952 109674953 0     
10 chr2  109674976 109674977 0.0370
# … with 61 more rows
```

Y esta la tabla que contiene las columnas con los filtros, siendo chromStart y chromEnd

```
  chrom chromStart  chromEnd encodeLabel ucscLabel
  <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>       <chr>    
1 chr2   109674587 109674828 PLS         prom     
2 chr2   109675982 109676183 PLS         prom     
3 chr2   109676214 109676416 pELS        enhP     
4 chr2   109676653 109676964 pELS        enhP
```

El objetivo final de mi trabajo es posteriormente asignar las etiquetas uscsLabel de cada intervalo a los valores que clasificaron para cada intervalo. Agradecería su ayuda o sugerencias.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor haz el [tour] y consulta [ask]. Debes mostrar lo que has intentado. De momento sólo indicas lo que debes hacer y eso **no es bien visto**. Aquí ayudamos a partir de lo que la gente intenta, no hacemos el trabajo por otros ni ofrecemos asesoría desde cero: te sugerimos como enfocar correctamente cuando has enfocado mal o te has equivocado, etc. Entra a [edit] y muestra tus avances. A partir de ellos será un gusto ayudarte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedo decir mucho sobre por que falla tu código, por que falta código para evaluarlo, pero creo que lo fundamental de tu pregunta es:

> El objetivo final de mi trabajo es posteriormente asignar las
> etiquetas uscsLabel de cada intervalo a los valores que clasificaron
> para cada intervalo.

Y, entiendo que estas apuntando bien, al menos en la idea, básicamente iterar sobre cada fila de `df1` y ver que fila de `df2` coincide con que `cromf` se encuentre entre `chromStart` y  `chromEnd` para luego asignar `ucscLabel`, esto puedes escribirlo mediante un ciclo explícito o bien uno implícito:

```
idx <- sapply(df1$cromf, function(x) {
  idx <- which(x >= df2$chromStart & x <= df2$chromEnd)
  if (length(idx) > 0) {idx[1]} else {0}}
)

df1$ucscLabel[idx>0] <- df2$ucscLabel[idx]
```

Con `sapply()` iteramos por cada `df1$cromf`, y en cada caso, con `idx <- which(x >= df2$chromStart & x <= df2$chromEnd)` buscamos el o los índices de la fila que coincida, finalmente retornamos 0 si no encontramos coincidencia y el índice encontrado:

Nota: Con `idx[1]` nos aseguramos de traer la primer coincidencia, si los rangos no se solapan entiendo que esto esto es innecesario.

Finalmente asignamos las etiquetas, en aquellas filas en las que hemos logrado hacer un "match": `df1$ucscLabel[idx>0] <- df2$ucscLabel[idx]`

---

Este problema, en un base de datos, es muy simple de resolver, se trata de un `join` condicional, con esto en mente, puedes usar el paquete `sqldf` que básicamente transforma tus `data.frame` en tablas de `sqlite` dónde luego es simple hacer una consulta SQL:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select a.*, b.ucscLabel
          from df1 a 
          left join df2 b 
          on (a.cromf > b.chromStart and a.cromf <= b.chromEnd) ")
```

Comment: Ha funcionado perfectamente! Profundamente agradecido Patricio!